# Master GIT repository with shared sub respoitories

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, repository, branch

I have created a basic admin system using **RoR**.  It has very basic functionality such as users, roles, security features and a basic UI.  I want to put this project into a master GIT repository.

If I want to create future projects, I'd like to use this base project as the foundation.  Do I create braches?

**MASTER PROJECT**

**MASTER PROJECT** > **SUB PROJECT #1**

**MASTER PROJECT** > **SUB PROJECT #2**

So both sub projects are identical to the master project at this point.  If I want to make a universal code change to any file within the **MASTER PROJECT**, how do I make that change trickle down to all sub projects.  That is my **FIRST QUESTION**.

**SECOND QUESTION:**

What if I want to make a code change to a particular file on one of the sub projects?

e.g.: If I customize the layout in **SUB PROJECT #2** (application.html.erb), I want that change only to affect **SUB PROJECT #2**.  I want all sub projects to use the application.html.erb from **MASTER PROJECT** UNLESS it has changed (customized).  It would be nice if **SUB PROJECT #2** only contained the one customized file.  All other missing files fallback on **MASTER PROJECT**.

**THIRD QUESTION:**

If I make a change to application.html.erb in the **MASTER PROJECT**, it is supposed to tickle that change down to all sub projects UNLESS one of the sub projects has a customized change to that file already.  In this case, **SUB PROJECT #2** does.

I'd want GIT to either:

a) Skip the update on application.html.erb on **SUB PROJECT #2**

OR

b) Prompt a warning to allow for some sort of merge.

Does that make sense?  Is this setup possible?  What would it be called?  Where do i start?

Answer (score 2):

**Question 1**:

You could use branches to track this. However, you should also consider whether what you need is simply a set of templates.

Git does not perform automatic merges by itself. You can write a script to do this, but otherwise you'll need to manually perform a `git merge` on each subproject branch.

**Question 2**:

Any branch you create will initially be identical to the original branch (master), at the time you created the branch. It will not change until you commit changes or merge in changes from the master branch. It wouldn't make sense to have this branch contain only the one customized file, so you may want to consider why you're asking for that if you want to use version control branches. The branch may only contain *modifications* to the one file, but nothing enforces this.

**Question 3**:

This is what git is designed for. When you do a `git merge` on the subproject branch, git will try to automatically merge the content and if it fails it will mark a conflict and allow you to manually perform a merge. You can also tell git to use another merge strategy, such as 'keep the local version', but this is a more advanced technique, and probably isn't what you want.

I recommend you start with the [git-tutorial](http://schacon.github.com/git/gittutorial.html) and make sure you have a good understanding of branching in git. Then, revisit this idea and make sure it still makes sense for what you're trying to acheive.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's the right choice to put your master project into its **own** repository and make a new one for each project. There's [git submodule](http://man.he.net/man1/git-submodule) which enables you to integrate other repositories in a project. YOu should try to have project specific changes only in the relating repositories, changes on the master project you can update via git submodule!